# @aws-amplify/ui-react Sign In page is not aligned

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I started to implement aws amplify with the AmplifyProvider to provide a basic login page.

However for some reason the styling is not what it used to be...

the sign in page is meant to be in the center and now there is also a large span on the right side that was not there before?

this is my index.js and my app.js has the withAuthenticator high order component... I have tried removing the style.css from index.js but then it leaves with no styling! no idea why its being aligned like this! help

```
import App from './App';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import config from './aws-exports';
import { AmplifyProvider } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

Amplify.configure(config);

ReactDOM.render(
   <AmplifyProvider>
     <App />
   </AmplifyProvider>,
   document.getElementById('root')
 );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

encountered the same thing -- in your css, add

```
[data-amplify-authenticator]{
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: hey would this go into the import css file? (aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css)

Comment: Nah just toss it in your main css file, should pick it up